# onclick href not firing inside click function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to fire a function on click the below link but its not firing

Here is my html code:

```
<li><a class="instlink" onclick="openInst();" href="#installations" >Installations</a></li>
```

My javascript is below

```
function openInst()
 {
    alert('here');//Its firing an alert
    $('.instlink').on('click', 'a', function (e) {
    alert("Fire"); //Its not producing an alert here.

    });
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that you `openInst()` is fired on a click, and then needs another click.

Instead, use:

```
<li><a class="instlink" href="#installations" >Installations</a></li>
```

```
 $('.instlink').on('click', function (e) {
    alert("Fire"); //Should fire
    location.hash = $(this).attr('href'); // This is probably what you are looking for
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is it:

brief

```
 <li><a class="instlink" onclick="openInst" myhash="#installations" >Installations</a></li>

function openInst()
     {
        alert('what you want');
       window.location.hash = $(this).attr('myhash');     
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

Replace your line

```
<li><a class="instlink" onclick="openInst();" href="#installations" >Installations</a></li>
```

with this line

```
<li><a class="instlink"  href="javascript:openInst('#installations')" >Installations</a></li>
```

and then in the

```
function openInst(hash){
location.hash=hash;
}
```